# Symfony 3 not loading validation constraints

Tags: forms, validation, location, symfony

I have recently upgraded from Symfony 2.8 to 3.1 and everything seems to be working fine except for the validation constraints. They are located in the `Resources/config/validation/` folder and follow the convention `Classname.yml`. In 2.8, the validator was picking them up perfectly fine but in 3.1 they are not loaded. I checked the documentation but there seems to be no information about change in the way they are loaded.

Has anyone experienced such a problem and found a solution?

Comment: Is validation till enabled in app/config.yml ?

Comment: yeah, it is. For some reason the FrameworkExtension class doesn't load the validation files.

Comment: Have you cleared the symfony cache by `bin/console cache:clear --no-debug` after upgrading?
I guess that FrameworkExtension reads the validation directories just once in order to compile the Container.